# World Health Organization API RGHO or WHO data in R

Tags: r, database

I'm trying to extract data from several indicators and countries.

I'm trying to use `rgho`package.

The only examples shown are:

```r
library(rgho)

result <- get_gho_data(
  code = "MDG_0000000001"
)

print(result)


result <- get_gho_data(
  code = "MDG_0000000001",
  filter = list(
    REGION = "EUR",
    YEAR = 2015
  )
)
```

I want to extract data from several indicators for several years and countries, for example:

```
indicators <- c('IHR01','IHR02','IHR03','IHR04','IHR05',
           'IHR06','IHR07','IHR08','IHR09','IHR10',
           'IHR11','IHR12','IHR13')
```

However when I input these inside the `code` argument I get an error.

It´s supposed to follow this page queries specification:
https://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.resources.api

But if in `filter(list = COUNTRY = "DOM,FRA")`, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

the get_gho_data function has parameters for both code and filter. The code parameter is used for specifying the indicator code, and the filter parameter is used for filtering the data based on certain criteria such as country and year.

Here's an example of how you can use the function to extract data for multiple indicators, years, and countries:

```
    library(rgho)

# Define the indicators, years, and countries
indicators <- c('IHR12', 'IHR13')
years <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014)  # Add the years you are interested in
countries <- c("DOM", "FRA", "USA")  # Add the countries you are interested in

# Initialize an empty list to store results
result_list <- list()

# Loop through indicators, years, and countries
for (indicator in indicators) {
  for (year in years) {
    for (country in countries) {
      # Construct the filter list
      filter_list <- list(
        COUNTRY = country,
        YEAR = year
      )
      
      # Get data for the current indicator, year, and country
      result <- get_gho_data(code = indicator, filter = filter_list)
      
      # Store the result in the list
      result_list[[paste(indicator, year, country, sep = "_")]] <- result
    }
  }
}

# Access the results using the names in the result_list
print(result_list)
```

I just tried it out, it needs a little time to fetch the data (especially when you have many countires and indicators.. i dont know if its the servers or an R issue) but i like using nested loops to iterate over indicators, years, and countries. It constructs a filter list for each combination of indicator, year, and country and retrieves the data using the get_gho_data function. The results are stored in a list (result_list) where each element is named based on the combination of indicator, year, and country.

Adjust the years and countries vectors according to your needs. This approach allows you to extract data for multiple indicators, years, and countries in a systematic way.

Comment: Is there a way to create a dataframe from all these lists?

Comment: `list2DF(result_list)` or `do.call("rbind", result_list)` are heavily used approaches.